# Jenkins pipeline can not access array

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having problems accessing environment variable in my shell of the Jenkins pipeline. How can I iterate over the array elements in my sh. See code below

```
def getArray(){
  return ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
      APP = getArray()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    for var in "${APP[@]}"   // does not work
                    do
                      echo "value : ${var}"  // How to echo this value i.e. Item1,Item2,Item3
                    done                    
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Environment variables (inside the environment block) are always strings, and cannot have any other value, therefore you should treat the APP parameter as a string in your sh step

Comment: Additionally, is there a compelling reason to do this in shell step methods? This would be significantly easier in native Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

The env variable automatically gets cast to the string type. So you can't store a value of an array type in the environment variable.Whatever is assiged to environmental variable is converted to `toString()`

You can use different options to solve this purpose by either giving a `,` separated string and use a `split` function to extract values.
You can also use `tokenize(",")` method to produce a list of elements which are separated by `,`.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
      APP="Item1, Item2, Item3"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                     env.APP.tokenize(",").each { item ->
                        echo "$item"
                    }
                    // OR //
                    APP = env.APP.split(",")
                    for (item in APP) {
                        echo "${item}"
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea, how can we define range using this approach:-                                       for (( i=0; i<${#APP[@]}; i++ ))    ?                                                                               it says unexpected char #